# Redirection after authentication in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have managed to make a login page that uses the WSO2 authentication, like https://192.168.56.1:9443/store/site/pages/login.jag. 
I can login through this using the same credentials that are for WSO2 server.

**Question:** How do I make it go to my page after I click on sign in?

By default, it takes me to https://192.168.56.1:9443/store

Suppose that I want it to redirect it to https://192.168.56.1:9443/store/site/pages/index.html

Comment: are you trying to implement your own store theme?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make my own API publishing store- the backend will be managed wholly by the WSO2 but the UI will be mine.